# Run some PHP code then redirect to a new page

Tags: php, html, redirect

I would like people to be able to click submit on a form, load a page where it checks some data then redirect to a whole new page. I know that you can use header() to redirect but you cant load anything with the header and I would like a loading animation between pages. What is the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Showing a loading animation only makes sense if you're processing data in a separate thread in the background and need to wait for it to complete. For a normal POST/redirect/GET cycle, that's both very troublesome to do and probably unnecessary. Does you operation take that long?

Comment: Technically speaking, you're right, but it's always nice for a user to see that something is happening, even if it doesn't take as long as the "loading" animation is shown. A "data submitted successfully" message is probably more realistic than "submitting data...", but the informative effect is the same in the end.

Comment: I know I dont need a loading animation, but as pdinklag it is nice to see something even if it is only 3 seconds or so. I might not use an animation but something like the data submitted successfully message. Just something they can see that it processed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would make the form submit its data to another page (something like `action="process.php"`).

That page processes whatever data your form sent, shows a nice "loading" text and animation and redirects the user to another page after a while.

This could be done using HTML's *meta refreshes*, which goes in your `<head>` and looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=anotherpage.php">
```

The `content` attribute is the interesting bit in there. The `3` means 3 seconds, `anotherpage.php` is the site redirected to after 3 seconds have passed.

Comment: Your PHP code is executed on the server side, way before the client will even know it is going to be redirected.

Comment: Depends on your server and your script. YOU have to take care that your script outputs the HTML before it starts processing the data. On many servers your php output is buffered and will be send when your script terminates. The result would be that your user would see the "processing" page when the processing is already finished. To get a proper processing page you should flush your output buffer and  use "ignore_user_abort" to make sure that your script is not terminated when the user is redirected. WARNING: Even if you flush the PHP output buffer there might be other buffers on the server.

Comment: For the record, I'd like to voice my rejection of this idea. Meta redirects are a hack and should not be used. However, a client-side redirect is the only way to do an intermediate page (which in itself should be avoided), if this is what the OP really wants.

Comment: Isn't this their exact purpose? I'm not sure where you're coming from here. Looking at most forum software, for instance, you get a message like "message posted successfully, you will be redirected to the thread...". Looks like an industry standard to me really, although I'm not sure how this is solved in such applications. Other than increased HTTP communication I cannot see any real drawback?

Comment: @pdi See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh, especially the links to W3C articles at the end. Also, just because it's popular doesn't mean it's good. Especially your average forum software is not exactly known for great technical feats.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative I'd suggest a minimal Javascript effect on the submitting page. `onsubmit` you disable the submit button and display a spinner or similar animation near it, maybe also adding a *"Processing..."* message. The page can then go through its normal POST/redirect/GET cycle, it's faster than going through an intermediate page and the user still has the feeling that something's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If headers have already been sent then this is the PHP/JavaScript code I use to send the browser to $newLocation:

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >', PHP_EOL;
echo '<!--', PHP_EOL;
echo '      window.top.location.href = \'', $newLocation, '\'', PHP_EOL;
echo '// -->', PHP_EOL;
echo '</script>', PHP_EOL;
```

In my case I'm using it to more controlably recover from error situations after a header has already been sent.

Answer (score -3):

To redirect in php, you use `header("Location: $url");`

Comment: header('Location: '.$url);